# Command-line input .CSV, search first column in web browser

Tags: shell, csv, unix, browser, command-line

Input file *stuff.csv*:

```
foobar,2,3
barfoo,5,6
feefifo,b,c
```

**Task**: take the first column of *stuff.csv* and search the web for each term.  Here's one way that works, it parses the above with `csvtool`, then opens each search term in a new `firefox` tab, using *DuckDuckGo*:

```
eval $(csvtool col 1 stuff.csv | \
       sed 's#.*#firefox -new-tab '"'"'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=&'"'"';#')
```

But [csvtool](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/csv/) isn't a standard util, `eval` can be pesky, the `sed` code is gnarly looking, and it uses a fixed search engine.  How can the above be made more portable and elegant, and preferably not depend on a specific search engine, or browser?

---

Q. inspired by, (or stolen from) - [Script to search lines from a .csv or .pdf on Google [on hold]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338588/script-to-search-lines-from-a-csv-or-pdf-on-google).

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut` and the *$BROWSER* variable, and skip `eval` and `sed` for something simple:

```
for item in $(cut -d ',' -f 1 stuff.csv); do \
    $BROWSER "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$item"  ; \
done
```

Comment: That looks like it might open many browser instances, *tabs* are preferred.

Comment: @agc, it depends on what your $BROWSER var is set to; mine is assigned to 'open' since I'm on OS X, where it nicely opens a new tab for each search item.